# AlertDialog showing unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

in my app I have a permissions method that checks and asks for permissions if build codes are >= 23, I have implemented AlertDialog to achieve this and show rationale if needed. The problem is when I test on lollipop a dialog window with the app's name pops up every time the app is started, I have fully protected all methods involved to not do anything if build codes are less than 23, so how and why is this dialog box still showing? Here's an image of the rouge dialog box:

[image]

And here is all the related code:

```
public void GMASInit() {
    linkGms = RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity;
    linkGms.startActivity(new Intent(linkGms, AudioSave.class));
}

protected void onStart() {//RunnerJNILib.ms_context
    super.onStart();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        getPerms();
    }
    //other unrelated code.....
}

public void getPerms() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    try { // Determine weather developer included optional WRITE_SETTINGS permission in the manifest
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(linkGms.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        if (info.requestedPermissions != null) {
            for (String p : info.requestedPermissions) {
                if (p.contains("WRITE_SETTINGS")) {
                    perms = 3;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {permissionsNeeded.add("Record Audio");}
    if(!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {permissionsNeeded.add("Write storage");}
    Log.i("yoyo","Number of permissions in manifest: " + String.valueOf(perms));
    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
                if (perms == 2) {
                    message = message + " " + msg1 + " and " + msg2 + " " + "to save and load data and record audio.";
                    }
                if (perms == 3) {
                    message = message + " " + msg1 + ", " + msg2 + " and " + msg3 + " " + "to save and load data, record audio and change ringtone.";
                    }
                Log.i("yoyo","Message to be shown: " + message);
                showMessageOKCancel(message, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (!Settings.System.canWrite(linkGms) && perms == 3) {
                        Intent writeset = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                        writeset.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + linkGms.getPackageName()));
                        linkGms.startActivity(writeset);
                    }
                    linkGms.requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]), Get_Permission);
                finish();
                }
            }
        });
        return;
        }
    }
    finish();
}
}

private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (linkGms.checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            if (!linkGms.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(linkGms).setTitle(msg0).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK", okListener).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create().show();
    }
}
```

As you can see I've gone overkill in trying to prevent this problem, Also note that it's only this dialog box showing (the one in the picture), the permissions dialog box does not show (which is expected). Also more info that might be helpfull/related is when testing android os 23 and up the dialog box I showed you shows above the permissions dialog box, and you have to click outside of it to dismiss it so the actual permissions dialog box can be accessed. please tell me where I've gone wrong and how to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was a strange situation indeed, it had nothing to do with the permissions or alert dialog builder at all, if fact I discovered it by removing all those methods and the alert dialog imports and it still happened, so instead the problem was related to my manifest activity level style code statement. I have this activity statement in my manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".AudioSave" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
</activity>
```

So this was causing a conflict with how I have to call the onStart method, but I need the theme for my app, so all I had to do to fix it was to add finish(); before the last closing curly bracket at the end of my onStart method. problem solved, like this:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
//bla bla bla...
finish();
}
```